# How to return an error from a returning value function in C language

Tags: c, embedded

I am wondering for a while what is the best practice to handle errors in returning values function in C. 
First, I would like to introduce the need then share a few solutions that I tried and to hear different ideas.

The issue is when I have a returning value function, this function can return any value in the range, and the function sometimes has a problem that it must return as well to the calling function, it cannot use the traditional return for that cause.
How can I handle that error in the calling function?

few notes:
1. I am an Embedded programer, and I am keen on keeping my function reentrant (pure) functions in a way that different interrupts won't harm the globals, I hardly use globals in my code.

2. I can't handle it with 0 or -1 because it is a valid return as well.
3. the errno solution doesn't support pure functions as well as 1.

4.I tried using structs of return which I have one field for the value and one field for the error if it has occurred.

```
unsigned int squre(unsigned int num)
{
return num*num;    
}
```

programmer say I would like to have handle for overflow.

```
struct returnUnsignedint squre(unsigned int num)
{
    struct returnUnsignedint returnValue;
    if (num>65535) { //my embedded system over flow
        returnValue.error = 1;
    }
    returnValue.value = num*num;
return returnValue;
}
```

is there a better option out there?

Let me know if you have different point of view, or solutions.

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: No "best practice".  Various approaches exist.  What is _best_ depends on the larger coding scheme.  Instead do not look at just how the error is signaled, but also how the error is to be handled by the calling code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no "one size fits all" solution, since it depends on needs of your program.

However, there are a few possibilities.

One way is to specify that one possible return value of your function can indicate an error occurred.   For example, since not every value of an `unsigned` is the square of another, pick a suitable value and return that.

```
 unsigned sqre(unsigned x)
 {
     if (x == 0U)
     {
        return 0U;
     }
     else if (UINT_MAX/x >= x)      /*  use fact that UINT_MAX is typically not a perfect square */
     {
        return x*x;
     }
     else
     {
        return UINT_MAX;
     }
 }
```

(Note, in the above, that I have eliminated your implicit assumption that `unsigned` is at least 32-bit, by avoiding use of the magic value `65535`).

Another option is to do what some standard library functions do:  return `0` (or, in the case of `unsigned`, return `0U`, on error) even if it is feasible that value is valid.    That means your function always returns a usable value, but the caller will need to decide what to do if your function returns zero.

Another option is to return a data structure

```
 struct Return
 {
       unsigned value;
       int error;
 };

 struct Return sqre(unsigned x)
 {
     struct Return retval;
     retval.error = 0;
     if (x == 0)
     {
        retval.value = 0U;
     }
     else if (UINT_MAX/x >= x)      /*  use fact that UINT_MAX is typically not a perfect square */
     {
        retval.value = x*x;
     }
     else
     {
        retval.error = 1;
     }
     return retval;
 }
```

The trade-off is that forces the caller to create an instance of the `struct` and then check or extract data from it.

Another is to provide a second argument that provides an error indication.

```
 unsigned sqre(unsigned x, int *error)
 {
     *error = 0;
     if (x == 0U)
     {
        return 0U;
     }
     else if (UINT_MAX/x >= x)      /*  use fact that UINT_MAX is typically not a perfect square */
     {
        return x*x;
     }
     else
     {
        *error = 1;
        return 0U;       /* falling off end without a return statement gives undefined behaviour */
     }
 }
```

The disadvantage of the above is that the caller can forget to check the error condition.    It is trivial to modify the above so it checks if `error` is `NULL` and then doesn't modify `*error`   (and then allow the caller to specify a `NULL` to indicate no interest in the error condition).

An alternative is for the function to return the error condition, and require the caller to pass the address of a variable to hold the result (if no error occurs).   A disadvantage of this is that the result from the function can't be used directly in larger expressions.

Since, technically, overflow of `unsigned` gives well-defined behaviour (essentially modulo arithmetic), use your version that does no checks.   This option isn't feasible if the function returns a `signed int` (since overflow gives undefined behaviour).   This requires the caller to deal with the fact that the returned value may be truncated (e.g. high order part of the value lost).

Yet another option is for the function to terminate with prejudice if an overflow would occur.  For example;

```
 unsigned sqre(unsigned x)
 {
     assert(x == 0 || UINT_MAX/x < x);   /*  from <assert.h> */
     return x*x;
 }
```

This removes the responsibility of the caller to check.   However, the caller (if program termination is undesirable) must then ensure the argument passed is valid.  Alternatively, the end-user would need to be willing to accept that the program may terminate on bad data.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to return the error code and write the output value to a parameter:

```
int sqr( unsigned int num, unsigned int *result )
{
  if ( num > 65535 )
    return 0;

  *result = num * num;
  return 1;
}
```

This isn’t always the most convenient option (especially if you want to use `sqr` as part of a larger arithmetic expression), but it should meet your requirements.

**EDIT**

Of course, you could always go the other way - return the value and write the error code to a parameter:

```
unsigned int sqr( unsigned int num, int *err ) { ... }
```

but frankly I prefer the first version, since you aren't tempted to use the return value unless you know the operation succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Following up [*John*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134554/john-bode)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199113/694576) I propose an additional macro to be able to use the function in a "*larger arithmetic expressions*"

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for EXIT_xxx macros */
#include <stdio.h>  /* for perror() */
#include <errno.h>  /* for errno */


int sqr(unsigned int num, unsigned int *psqr)
{
  int result = 0;

  if (NULL == psqr)
  {
    result = -1;
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else if (num > 0xffffU)
  {
    result = -1;
    errno = ERANGE;
  }
  else
  {
    *psqr = num * num;
  }

  return result;
}

#define SQR(x, y) \
  ((-1 == sqr(x, &y)) \
    ? (perror("sqr() failed"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE), 0U) \
    : y \
  )
```

Some tests below (please note that the macro SQR() has to end the program if sqr() fails):

```
int main(void)
{
  unsigned int r, i;

  puts("Test case 1:");
  i = 42;
  if (-1 == sqr(i, &r))
  {
    perror("sqr() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("sqr(%u) = %u\n", i, r);
  }   

  puts("Test case 2:");
  i = 0x10000;
  if (-1 == sqr(i, &r))
  {
    perror("sqr() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("sqr(%u) = %u\n", i, r);
  }

  puts("Test case 3:");
  if (-1 == sqr(i, NULL))
  {
    perror("sqr() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("sqr(%u) = %u\n", i, r);
  }

  puts("Test case 4:");
  r = SQR(1, r) + SQR(2, r);
  printf("sqr(%u) + sqr(%u) = %u\n", 1, 2, r);

  puts("Test case 5:");
  r = SQR(0x10000, r) + SQR(2, r);
  printf("sqr(%u) + sqr(%u) = %u\n", 0x10000, 2, r); 

  puts("Test case 6:");
  r = SQR(NULL, r) + SQR(2, r);
  printf("sqr(%u) + sqr(%u) = %u\n", 0x10000, 2, r); 

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is:

```
Test case 1:
sqr(42) = 1764
Test case 2:
sqr() failed: Numerical result out of range
Test case 3:
sqr() failed: Invalid argument
Test case 4:
sqr(1) + sqr(2) = 5
Test case 5:
sqr() failed: Numerical result out of range
```

Test case 6 is never reached as test case 5 ends the program.